# SQL Query to combine some rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Output of my current query is like:

```
item    number
car     5
bus     4
bicycle 7
kaikias 10
```

but I need to group the item by whether it is a motor vehicle or not. But this information is not in the DB. I should explicity say that car is a motor vehicle in the query. Expected output is:

```
item   number
motor  9
others 17
```

How can I combine rows by their some property which is not in DB?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way would be to create a new table for this information, join the tables and group by the category.

Otherwise you can do something similar with in's and case's, but it doesn't scale well, and hacky.

Like this:

```
select
  case when item in ('motor1', 'motor2', '...') then 'motors' else 'others' end item,
  count(*) number
from
  table
group by
  case when item in ('motor1', 'motor2', '...') then 'motors' else 'others' end
```

Answer (score 2):

You only can query and group items by the Information you have in your database. It's not possible that your database knows by itself, that a car has a motor or a bicycle don't have a motor.

If it's possible i would recommend that you add a new column where you save such information.

**EDIT:**

If you just want to indicate for known values you can try it this way:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (item = 'car' OR item = 'bus') THEN 'motor' ELSE 'others' END as item, ...
FROM yourTable
...
```

First Parameter is your condition, second parameter your value for `true`, third parameter the value for `false`.

Comment: But can I indicate that car and bus are motor vehicle in the query?